# rdd.saveAsCassandraTable()creates table but does not write rdd items to Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am trying to create a log processing application using Scala (2.11), Spark Streaming (1.5.0) and Cassandra(3.5). At the moment, on receiving the first set of rdd items and running foreachRDD(...) shown below,

1. The first element in the set is printed without any problems
2. The saveAsCassandraTable() method correctly creates the required table schema in Cassandra but does not insert any of the RDD entries in the table.

   ```
   logitems.foreachRDD(items => {
     if (items.count() == 0)
       println("No log item received")
     else{
       val first = items.first()
       println(first.timestamp)  // WORKS: Shows the timestamp in the first rdd element

       items.saveAsCassandraTable("analytics", "test_logs", SomeColumns("timestamp", "c_ip", "c_referrer", "c_user_agent"))
       //table schema is created but the rdd items are not written
     }
   })



   16/05/19 16:15:06 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /192.168.1.95:9042 added
   16/05/19 16:15:06 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreachRDD at StreamingApp.scala:27
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 8 (foreachRDD at StreamingApp.scala:27) with 8 output partitions
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 6(foreachRDD at StreamingApp.scala:27)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at StreamingApp.scala:24), which has no missing parents
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(13272) called with curMem=122031, maxMem=1538166620
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 13.0 KB, free 1466.8 MB)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5909) called with curMem=135303, maxMem=1538166620
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.8 KB, free 1466.8 MB)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on localhost:63323 (size: 5.8 KB, free: 1466.8 MB)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 8 missing tasks from ResultStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at StreamingApp.scala:24)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 6.0 with 8 tasks
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 34, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 35, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 36, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 37, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 38, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 39, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 40, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1943 bytes)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 34)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 35)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 38)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 39)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 37)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 36)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO Executor: Running task 6.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 40)
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_6 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_3 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_4 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_2 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_1 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_5 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:07 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_9_0 locally
   16/05/19 16:15:10 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667310000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667315000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:20 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667320000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:25 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667325000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667330000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:35 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667335000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667340000 ms
   16/05/19 16:15:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667345000 ms

   .... continues until program is manually terminated
   ```

I'll be glad to have any pointers regarding where to look to fix this.

[image: spark ui]

I have attached a screenshot of the spark ui.

Comment: Do you see any other errors?

Comment: None... Only repeated messages saying (16/05/19 16:15:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1463667345000 ms) until I have to kill the job

Comment: On waiting about 20 minutes into the task, I got the following error `16/05/19 23:36:04 ERROR QueryExecutor: Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@2c166223`
`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)`
 at `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException.copy(UnavailableException.java:128)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the subsequent calls to `saveAsCassandraTable` are failing because the Table already exists. You should probably make the table outside the streaming loop.

I would check to see if switching to `saveToCassandra` fixes the problem. If it doesn't it may help to get executor logs or a screenshot of the Streaming UI.

Comment: Hi RussS, I actually started out with saveToCassandra(), but got the same behaviour. Then I switched to saveAsCassandraTable() just to be sure Spark was actually reaching Cassandra. But you are definately right about using saveAsCassandraTable within the the foreach call - I'll revert to the former.

Comment: Can paste what you see in the streaming UI?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the spark ui. Normally processing my small dataset only takes a couple of milliseconds without the **saveToCassandra()** step. But, with this step, it keeps going for minutes until I kill the task.

Comment: I am running it as a local job with "local[*]", so I am assuming it uses all the available cores

Comment: The error you added shows an availability issue. Are you sure that all the required nodes are up?

Comment: I am actually only running on a single node (local) for development only

Comment: Then i suggest you change the replication on your keyspace to not specify multiple nodes